# Teradata conversion of timestamp(0) to AM/PM format

Tags: teradata, teradata-sql-assistant, teradatasql

I have one table with below data. Data type of START_TIME is timestamp(0) & AVG_RUN_TIME_MINS is Integer.
I want to print **EXPECTED_COMPLETION_TIME** which is equal to - (**START_TIME + AVG_RUN_TIME_MINS**) and output will be in format like - '10:00 AM' or '08:00 PM'.

How to achieve this scenario?

```
START_TIME             AVG_RUN_TIME_MINS
----------------------------------------
8/27/2020 06:14:49             120
8/27/2020 16:10:28             3
8/27/2020 06:01:05             60
8/27/2020 05:50:30             85
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the minutes to the start time and use TO_CHAR to disply it as a string:

```
to_char(START_TIME + cast(AVG_RUN_TIME_MINS as interval minute(4)), 'hh:mi AM')
```